# Vue dynamically create computed after init

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to create a computed dynamically after the initialization of the component?

I don't know beforehand the name the computed should have.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 'Is it possible to create a computed dynamically after the initialization of the component?' no, you cannot. But most of the time you can approach the problem a different way, which does not require a computed component.

Answer (score -4):

Computed properties are similar to methods where as computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
      {{reverseMessage}}
      Message: <input v-model="message"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
      message: ''
     },
     computed: {
      reverseMessage: () => {
        return this.message.reverse();
      }
     }
    });
</script>
```

This means as long as message has not changed, multiple access to the reversedMessage computed property will immediately return the previously computed result without having to run the function again.

Where as if it was written in **methods** then it will re-evaluate every-time when the view re-renders.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question about creating computed properties dynamically